# Play button for video thumbnail

Tags: facebook, video, button, thumbnails, playback

What do I have to do to get the play button on a video thumbnail?
I tried using open graph parameters to show facebook that the URL is a website containing a video but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a Flash video file associated with the page places a play button over your thumbnail image (now essentially a poster frame) and loads your linked video file on a user click or tap. It's possible to specify multiple video formats with an array of structured video properties: Flash, MP4, and WebM for example. Facebook currently supports Flash and HTML video links, roughly correlated to  and  content includes on your own web pages. Everything in one URL means you will have to move your FlashVars into query parameters except; width and height FlashVars are passed by Facebook at runtime.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/movie.swf?id=1">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example.com/movie.swf?id=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300">
```

The "secure_url" property is required to play inline video for users browsing Facebook with HTTPS enabled. Facebook does not currently support direct MP4 or WebM videos but may add support in the future through a Facebook video playback wrapper. Publishers need to account for framed content with AllowScriptAccess set to "none."